# Windows 10 no internet if hotspot on

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, hotspot

I have a Windows 10 desktop, and after the update (https://support.microsoft.com/help/5014699) I don't have internet if I turn on the hotspot, but I have it instantly if I turn off the hotspot.

Can you tell me please why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-28-2022-kb5014666-os-builds-19042-1806-19043-1806-and-19044-1806-preview-4bd911df-f290-4753-bdec-a83bc8709eb6 to resolve this issue

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I couldn't find related questions, neither in search nor in the related  questions finder, despite I gave exactly these keywords. I don't understand why it doesn't show them...

Comment: Use Google to find SU questions